# How to use multer with swagger?

Tags: node.js, express, upload, swagger, multer

I've been going through the multer docs.This is how we can use multer to upload files on the server (using nodeJs and express) :

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

But while using swagger (with express framework) , we can only have (req,res) in the params of the route handler as in:
**function routeHandler(req,res)**. How can I add the extra parameters *upload.single('avatar')* in swagger route handler.

---

Or is there another way to use multer with swagger ?

Comment: Are you asking how to properly document file upload with swagger?

Comment: Your looking for this? https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/